# GITHUB Branching & Merging Challenges

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework

We have a team of 6 automation QA resources.

We are using GitHub to update our automation scripts and merge to master. This project contains test cases for smoke and regression test scenarios. It seems that Team was facing issues while trying to merge their work in Master branch, as a result, they have created multiple master branches and other branches to save their work.

I joined this team recently. Would need some advice to clean up this mess and follow clean branching strategy without merge conflicts. This is for QA automation work and scripts not for the development team.

Please share your inputs and suggestions.

Comment: not good fit for sqa site. It is automation work, but your question is really about git. I would use stackoverflow for that.

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian explains a few different possible Git Workflows: [Comparing Git Worflows.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows)

In particular, you may want to see the [GitFlow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)
[image]

When some conflict happen between one of the *feature* branch and the *develop* branch, GiHub will show you:

[image]

Then, the developers just need to rebase his branch against the newest *develop* branch:

```
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/develop
git push -f
```

But this only ensures the merging ability.
If you want to ensure that you have a green build (that the merging would not break the business flow of the tests), you also may want to [run your tests on every commit in a CI tool](http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html).